# Midi files not working on Rhythmbox  nor VLC

Tags: rhythmbox, vlc, gstreamer, midi

- Rhythmbox 2.96 doesn't run any midi file on Ubuntu 12.04, even after installing GStreamer and Ubuntu Restricted Extras.
- Rhythmbox-Message: Missing plugin: gstreamer|0.10|rhythmbox-metadata|audio/midi decoder|decoder-audio/midi
- [0xb5504e40] main decoder error: no suitable decoder module for fourcc `MIDI'. VLC probably does not support this sound or video format.

Comment: run the file in terminal and post the output of the error

Comment: @Ashu: Rhythmbox-Message: Missing plugin: gstreamer|0.10|rhythmbox-metadata|audio/midi decoder|decoder-audio/midi

Answer (score 21):

You can play midi with VLC. Just install `vlc-plugin-fluidsynth`

```
sudo apt install vlc-plugin-fluidsynth
```

Comment: This is the only thing that has ever worked for me.

Comment: worked for me Ubuntu 20.04.1

Answer (score 3):

Usually audio-players do not support playing midi file, that strictly speaking are not audio files.

You can play midi file through a MIDI software synthesizer, like Timidity or Fluidsynth.

In the Rhythmbox FAQ you find the following question:

> #### Can I use MIDI files with Rhythmbox?
>
> Rhythmbox uses the GStreamer media framework for actual playback and a
> lot of other functionality, so in general Rhythmbox plays exactly
> those formats that are supported by GStreamer. GStreamer, on the other
> hand, uses a plugin system where each format is supported by a plugin.
> Thus, the formats supported by GStreamer (and Rhythmbox) depends on
> which plugins you have installed. Different distributions may ship
> with a different set of plugins by default.
>
> To look for plug-ins, go to
> http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/ . The [Wildmidi](http://wildmidi.sourceforge.net/) plugin
> works fine with rhythmbox.

so if you still want to use Rhythmbox for midi files, take a look at the mentioned Wildmidi project.

Comment: i did "sudo apt-get install wildmidi" and still no change.

Answer (score -1):

### Install Gstreammer 0.10

Open your Terminal, copy and paste:

`sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-gnonlin gstreamer0.10-sdl gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-schroedinger gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly totem-plugins-extra`

`sudo apt-get install gstreamer-dbus-media-service gstreamer-tools ubuntu-restricted-extras`
that should do it

Comment: "Rhythmbox-Message: Missing plugin: gstreamer|0.10|rhythmbox-metadata|audio/midi decoder|decoder-audio/midi" and **VLC outputs "[0xb5504e40] main decoder error: no suitable decoder module for fourcc `MIDI'. VLC probably does not support this sound or video format.
"

Comment: MIDI is not a proprietary format, so ubuntu-restricted extras and gstreamer doesn't help.